# RichFaces button enable disable based on a4j:status

Tags: java, richfaces, jsf-2.2

My requirement is that `a4j:commandButton` should be disable on click, it should remain disabled till data is loaded in `rich:dataTable`.

Can you please tell me how can we implement it. Can we use `a4j:status` for this. I am already using `a4j:status` for showing progress. Can we capture start and end flag of `a4j:status` and based on that we can enable and disable `a4j:commandButton` .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you're using JQuery:

```
 <a4j:commandButton onbegin="$(this).prop('disabled',true);" oncomplete="$(this).prop('disabled',false);" />
```

When you click on the button the onbegin JS is called and when your AJAX request completes, the oncomplete will be called which will enable the button again.

If not using JQuery use plain javascript (foo is your element):

```
foo.disabled = true;
foo.disabled = false;
```

Comment: code snippet is given below      <a4j:commandButton id="Search" value="[ Search ]" 
  style=" margin-left: 60px; height: 25px; margin-bottom: 7px;" 
  onbegin="$(this).prop('disabled',true);"  
     onclick="resetSearch();doSearch();"
 oncomplete="$(this).prop('disabled',false);"/>
<a4j:jsFunction name="resetSearch" action="#{abc.resetSearch}" reRender="Search,searchResultPanel" />
<a4j:jsFunction name="doSearch" action="#{abc.Search}" reRender="Search,searchResultPanel" />

Comment: `<a4j:commandButton id="Search" value="[ Search ]" style=" margin-left: 60px; height: 25px; margin-bottom: 7px;" onbegin="$(this).prop('disabled',true);" onclick="resetSearch();doSearch();" oncomplete="$(this).prop('disabled',false);"/> <a4j:jsFunction name="resetSearch" action="#{abc.resetSearch}" reRender="Search,searchResultPanel" /> <a4j:jsFunction name="doSearch" action="#{abc.Search}" reRender="Search,searchResultPanel" />`